# Tracking Payment Method Changes in WooCommerce order notes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a WooCommerce project where I need to record and log any changes made to the payment method in the backend. I want to capture who made the changes and when they were made. To achieve this, I've written some code, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected.

```
// Add note when payment method changes from WooCommerce admin order details page
add_action('woocommerce_saved_order_items', 'add_note_on_payment_method_change', 10, 2);
function add_note_on_payment_method_change($order_id, $order) {
    if (is_admin() && isset($_POST['payment_method'])) {
        $new_payment_method = sanitize_text_field($_POST['payment_method']);
        $old_payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

        if ($new_payment_method !== $old_payment_method) {
            // Get the current user and date/time
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $date_time = current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            // Add admin note for payment method change
            $note = sprintf(
                'Payment method changed to %s by %s on %s',
                $new_payment_method,
                $current_user->display_name,
                $date_time
            );
            $order->add_order_note($note);

            // Save the changes
            $order->save();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be more awesome if we can add an order note whenever there's a change in biiling, shipping details as well.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you I did test and its work on my system

My code is here .

```
// Add note when payment method or address changes from WooCommerce admin order details page
add_action('woocommerce_saved_order_items', 'add_note_on_order_changes', 10, 2);

function add_note_on_order_changes($order_id, $order) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        $changed = false;
        $note = "";

        // Check payment method change
        if (isset($_POST['payment_method'])) {
            $new_payment_method = sanitize_text_field($_POST['payment_method']);
            $old_payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();

            if ($new_payment_method !== $old_payment_method) {
                $note .= sprintf(
                    'Payment method changed to %s. ',
                    $new_payment_method
                );
                $changed = true;
            }
        }

        // Check billing details change
        $billing_fields = array(
            'billing_first_name', 'billing_last_name', 'billing_company',
            'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city',
            'billing_postcode', 'billing_country', 'billing_state',
            'billing_email', 'billing_phone'
        );

        foreach ($billing_fields as $field) {
            if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                $new_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]);
                $old_value = $order->get_meta('_'.$field);

                if ($new_value !== $old_value) {
                    $note .= sprintf(
                        '%s changed to %s. ',
                        ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)),
                        $new_value
                    );
                    $changed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check shipping details change
        $shipping_fields = array(
            'shipping_first_name', 'shipping_last_name', 'shipping_company',
            'shipping_address_1', 'shipping_address_2', 'shipping_city',
            'shipping_postcode', 'shipping_country', 'shipping_state'
        );

        foreach ($shipping_fields as $field) {
            if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
                $new_value = sanitize_text_field($_POST[$field]);
                $old_value = $order->get_meta('_'.$field);

                if ($new_value !== $old_value) {
                    $note .= sprintf(
                        '%s changed to %s. ',
                        ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $field)),
                        $new_value
                    );
                    $changed = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if ($changed) {
            // Get the current user and date/time
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $date_time = current_time('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $note .= sprintf(
                'Changes made by %s on %s.',
                $current_user->display_name,
                $date_time
            );

            $order->add_order_note($note);

            // Save the changes
            $order->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me.

Comment: Some explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem (or should - not sure why the comment says it's not working but accepted the answer).

Comment: Hey @NigelRen I want to record the changes made in billing & shipping details including changes made to payment method in order notes, many customers chose COD as MOD on website but when order is delivered, they make payment via credit/debit card our customer support team changes the MOD for those orders from backend & I want to record those changes. there are several changes made to order after the orders are placed and I want to record those changes in order notes for integrity purposes.